# Get filter plugin query for an enhanced grid

Tags: javascript, dojo

In my scenario I have an enhanced grid with a filter plugin. When the filter plugin is activated, I want to retrieve the filter query (values, conditions, columns and logicany - see comment in code).

After that I want to set the filter null and set a new filter with the same query programmatically. Don't ask why I do something like this :D But I need that for a bigger scenario.

Here the code snippet for my scenario and the TODO comment.

```
if (grid.layer("filter")._filter != null) {
console.log(grid.layer("filter"));

// TODO: How do I get the query "value" and "condition" for each "column"? In addition how do I get like here the "logicany"? 
// Something like:
// grid.layer("filter").getJsonQuery?!

grid.setFilter(null);

// Here I set it manually, but I want to set the retrieved values.
grid.setFilter([{
    type: 'string',
    column: 1,
    condition: 'contains',
     value: 'Test'
    }, {
    type: 'number',
    column: 2,
    condition: 'lessthan',
    value: 100
}], 'logicany');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do :

```
grid.getFilter()
```

This returns an array of filter object, each object having the following properties :

```
{
    colTxt: "Year"
    column: "3"
    condTxt: "contains"
    condition: "contains"
    formattedVal: "2003"
    type: "string"
    value: "2003"
}
```

Comment: Where do I get the match parameters from? I want to know whether it is logicany or logicall.

Comment: Try grid.getFilterRelation()